# how to use passport-remember-me with a user database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I've been trying for the last few days to get passport-remember-me up and running in a node js app I'm working on. My passport-local strategy (working with passport-local-mongoose) has been working fine but trying to incorporate remember-me functionality is proving to be a nightmare (due to my own ignorance). I have spent the last couple of days searching but I haven't found an example that uses the passport-remember-me strategy alongside passport-local and passport-local-mongoose while storing data in a database. The example that is provided [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-remember-me/tree/master/examples/login) uses a fake database of tokens and users (in-memory/on the server) but I want to know how I should link it up so that I can use an actual mongodb database.

So, my basic question is: How should the existing example code linked to above be modified so that users and tokens are stored in/retrieved from a mongodb database? The aim is to do this while using passport-local-mongoose, passport-local and passport-remember-me, rather than writing custom strategies or middlewares.